# How to Convert Big sized videos and images into NSData in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm uploading videos and images to a remote server, and using the following code to convert them to nsdata:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
//NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
```

for small sized videos and images, this code is working fine but for large videos or images, the app is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions proposed is to partition those images and videos and upload them part by part.

> 1. Open file to upload.
> 2. read, let's say 5mb.
> 3. put them on NSDATA. 4 upload it.
> 4. clear NSDATA.

Repeat form point 2.